# nfs-common (statd) no longer starting

Tags: linux, nfs

I have a pretty standard Debian 5.0.2 system (2.6.26-2-amd64 kernel), with a 4-core Phenom processor.  Everything has been working great for years, and suddenly during a reboot, I got an error message about statd failing.

Indeed, I didn't have any network interface.

I was able to bring up eth0 with:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

But there was no ipv4 address.  I added a static address with:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.248
```

and, then brought up eth0, and restarted networking.  [This is the address my router has reserved and forwards to for this server, so that's why I'm not using DHCP].  At least I had an interface again.  I can ssh into the machine, and Apache is serving pages again.  So it appears that the networking card, cable, and router are all still working well.

For good measure, I restarted portmap.

Now, at least, I get the following:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:8c:c2:03:2c
          inet addr:192.168.0.248  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:8cff:fec2:32c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2131 errors:0 dropped:49777272750 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:151268 (147.7 KiB)  TX bytes:61530 (60.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:254 Base address:0x2000
```

Well, when I try to restart nfs-common, I again get a "failed!" message:

```
# /etc/init.d/nfs-common restart
Stopping NFS common utilities: statd.
Starting NFS common utilities: statd failed!
```

Also, I still cannot ping from the machine, receiving an unknown host error.

```
# ping www.ping.com
ping: unknown host www.ping.com
```

And I cannot ssh off the machine (receiving a "name or service not known error"), but I can ssh into the machine just fine.

Finally, when I reboot, I have to manually add the IP address again.  This, despite the fact that the correct info is still in the interfaces file:

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces

# --------------
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Static address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
         address 192.168.0.248
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         network 192.168.0.0
         broadcast 192.168.0.255
         gateway 192.168.0.1
```

I can't think of anything that might have changed to cause this problem. I searched my root history to verify that I hadn't been doing anything.

This did follow, however, a hard shut-down due to a prolonged power failure.  I don't think there was a surge.  All the drives checked fine on reboot.  Just the networking seemed messed up.

Any help or hints you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

-- Madeleine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `auto eth0` please try `allow-hotplug eth0`.

Comment: Janne, I made the change, but it didn't change any of the issues above [i.e., loading nfs-common still fails, must manually add IP address, etc.]